# ng-select Dropdown not opening after limit reach

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, multi-select, angular-ngselect

In multi select dropdown when limit is reached. It doesn't open.
It is not correct for every use case.
I want to show selected items. SO, he can uncheck them in manually from the dropdown.
I am not showing all items selected, just the count of total selected items.
So can't remove selected item easily. That's why I want to open the dropdown.

If limit is reached. Dropdown won't open and I can't remove a specific selection.
I want to remove specific items from the list manually.

```
   <label>Multiselect with custom bindings</label>
    <ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               bindValue="id"
               [multiple]="true"
               [maxSelectedItems]="3"
               [closeOnSelect]="false"
               groupBy="selectedAllGroup"
               [selectableGroup]="true"
               placeholder="Select cities"
               (change)="onMaterialGroupChange($event)">

        <ng-template 
                ng-optgroup-tmp let-item="item" 
                let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
                <input id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox"
                [ngModel] ="item$.selected"/> Select All
        </ng-template>
    </ng-select>


    <p>
        Selected cities: {{selectedCityIds}}
    </p>

    <div style="margin-top:300px"></div>

this.cities = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Amar' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Akbhar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Anthony' },
  { id: 4, name: 'BadkaG' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Baave' },
]
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @MehyarSawas code added
You can check it out in  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-py4u8j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json

Comment: In your stackblitz example the dropdown always opens.

Comment: I have fixed above issue changing maxSelectedItems values in the open and close events.
By default the value will be set as options array length when it opens once the value will be changed to required limit once it's closed that close event will be executed with in the method set that limit to array length.
This method works for me.

Comment: As in @DA answer it is probably a version bug, because this behavior is not reproducible on the official documentation on ng-select github which probably uses the latest version. But if you are not willing to upgrade angular, then go ahead with your working workaround

Comment: ng-select developers mention in the open issue that this is by design https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1131 but it seems that have changed their mind afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Update the package version from `@ng-select/ng-select` 2.16.0 to 10.0.1. I've used angular 15 and added your forgotten line `[maxSelectedItems]="3"` and now it opens.

Comment: The problem is probably solved by your solution, but if for some reason angular upgrade is not an option, a workaround solution is needed